# Math.round vs. math.ceil yields unexpected results

Tags: javascript

The user may input a value or a simple expression as a division.
The output should be a value to 2 decimal places.
e.g.

```
8.50 should yield 8.50
4/2 should yield 2.00
```

But if the input is a division resulting in a fractional value, the output should be rounded up.
e.g.

```
500/3 should yield 166.67
```

Using the following calculation:

```
var fieldVal = 500/3;
fieldVal = Math.ceil(fieldVal * 100) / 100;
fieldVal; // yields 166.67 - good
```

But if `fieldVal = 8.88` the calc yields `8.89`

If I use:

```
var fieldVal = 8.88;
fieldVal = Math.round(fieldVal * 100) / 100;
fieldVal; // yields 8.88 - good
```

But:

```
var fieldVal =  500/6.95;
fieldVal = Math.round(fieldVal * 100) / 100;
fieldVal; // yields 71.94
```

But I want `71.95` since `500/6.95` yields `71.942`... (because I want to round up in such a case)

I'm at a loss. What is the solution here?

Comment: why do you call `fieldVal = eval(fieldVal);`  ? it's useless here.

Comment: what @PierreEmmanuelLallemant said. AND eval is evil!

Comment: also if you want to round up from 71.942 to 7.95 you're not going to make that work in ANY numerical system ;)

Comment: `eval` is fantastically useful, but should be used carefully..

Comment: @Xotic750 as in "thoughtfully" and "only where you really need it", which shouldn't be the case here as it's a completely useless statement seemingly used to convert a float to itself here ;)

Comment: *eval* is absolutely useless here.  And there seems to be missing why 71.942 can be round up to 7.95... As @nonchip mentioned. Perhaps it was meant to be "71.95"

Comment: Yes, useless in this example.

Comment: even then, 71.942 is supposed to round down when using round instead of ceil. @AlphaBase: did you actually answer just your own question in it's title?

Comment: I think the question is a bit unclear, and had to be read a few times to understand what the actual problem is.  As I see it, your question is how to make a universal function using either `.ceil` or `.round` that works with all possible values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it in a simple way.

The problem is that the computer stores numbers in base 2, and has a finite precision. Then, your `8.88` becomes

```js
8.88000000000000078159700933611020445823669433593750
```

According to your rules, it is rounded up to `8.89`.

A solution could be multiplying your quantities by 100 (in the source code, not using JS), and divide them by 100 at the end.

```
var fieldVal100 = 888; // 8.88 * 100
fieldVal100 = Math.ceil(fieldVal100);
var fieldVal = fieldVal100 / 100; // 8.88

var fieldVal100 = 50000/3; // 500/3 * 100
fieldVal100 = Math.ceil(fieldVal100);
var fieldVal = fieldVal100 / 100; // 166.67

var fieldVal100 = 50000/6.95; // 500/6.95 * 100
fieldVal100 = Math.ceil(fieldVal100);
var fieldVal = fieldVal100 / 100; // 71.95
```

Another solution would be storing the numbers as strings instead of numbers, and use some library which operates those strings in base 10.

Comment: that's why banking tools calculate in cents, not dollars, and just add the dot in when displaying the result ;)

Comment: @nonchip unless you're writing banking tools that divide sums. Then you have the integer truncation problem.

Comment: if your int is big enough, dividing it after summing should be no problem, as you're not going to give your customers half cents anyway. that's where round comes into play

Answer (score 2):

If you want to round up use `ceil()` and not `round()`:

```
fieldVal = Math.ceil(fieldVal * 100) / 100;
```

If you round `7194.2` you will get `7194` and not `7195`, hence leading to `71.94`.

The reason why `8.88 * 100` is going to `8.89` is because the way computers store decimal numbers. Because they cannot represent all possible decimals they are approximated to a degree. So `8.88 * 100 = 888.0000000000001`, which using `ceil` leads to `889`.

Comment: I think you didn't understood the question. OP already tried this, but when `fieldVal == 8.88`, the result is supposed to be `8.88`, not `8.89`..

Comment: @Oriol See for yourself `Math.ceil(88.88 * 100) / 100;` yields `8.88` not `8.89`. Math.ceil is the correct approach here since the OP wants to round `71.94244604316546` up to `71.95` even though the thousandth place isn't 5 or bigger.

Comment: @Ultimater `Math.ceil(8.88 * 100) / 100` is `8.89`. Of course `Math.ceil` is the correct approach, OP already says it. As I [explained](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34503101/1529630), the problem is in the numbers themselves.

Comment: @Oriol Ah, I was using 88.88 not 8.88, oops, I miscopied the number somehow.  Not even sure where I got that number from. Yeah, `8.88 * 100` yields `888.0000000000001`. For this type of thing, you need to floor off the noise... This should work: `Math.ceil(Math.floor((8.88 * 100)*10000000000)/10000000000)/100`

Comment: @Ultimater Unfortunately there isn't really a fool-proof way to handle this. Because the user might want it to be some low decmial number in some cases, I could attempt to remove it by doing something like `+(8.88 * 100).toPrecision(14);`, although the user might input something like `+(9999999999999999/9999999999999998 * 100).toPrecision(14);` and not want to have a interger.

Answer (score 0):

**the basic difference...**

The Math.floor() returns or round off always down i.e. **Math.floor(3.8)** will give the result as **3**.

The Math.round returns or round off always to the **nearest** integer i.e. **Math.round(3.8)** yields **4** as the nearest integer possible.

The Math.ceil() returns or round off always upwards i.e. **Math.ceil(3.8)** yields **4** as nearest upward integer.